# Why should I use an interface for a GraphQL mutation response type?

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo-server

In reading the Apollo Server documentation, it recommends using a mutation response interface for mutations:

> In order to provide consistency across a schema, we suggest
>   introducing a `MutationResponse` interface which can be implemented on
>   every mutation response in a schema and enables transactional
>   information to be returned in addition to the normal mutation response
>   object.

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/essentials/schema.html

I understand the benefit of interfaces for use cases where you have an **events** interface and then you have different types of events such as a concert, conference, etc. My understanding is an interface would allow you to search all events with a single query for example, returning multiple types of events.

I am confused why an interface should be used for a mutation response and what the benefits would be over a standard response type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like a Union, an Interface is an abstract type that allows a field to return one of multiple types. From the spec:

> Fields which yield an interface are useful when one of many Object types are expected, but some fields should be guaranteed.

However, interfaces also force implementing types to have a specific set of fields and arguments. The exact rules can be found [here](https://facebook.github.io/graphql/draft/#sec-Objects) in the spec, but it boils down to:

- If the interface has a field, the implementing type must also have that field
- The implementing type must also have the same arguments for any of these fields (like fields, it can add additional ones, but must at least implement the same ones as the interface)
- The types of these required fields and arguments must match the interface
- If the type of a required field or interface is Non-Null, it must also be Non-Null on the implementing type (although the reverse is not true)

By creating an Interface and having multiple types implement it, you effectively create a safety net that will help you ensure a consistent structure across related types. Let's assume we implement some response types as suggested in the Apollo docs, without an interface:

```
type UpdateUserMutationResponse {
  code: String!
  success: Boolean!
  message: String!
  user: User
}

type UpdatePostMutationResponse {
  code: String!
  success: Boolean!
  message: String
  post: Post
}
```

At a glance, these types are defined as we intended -- we have fields for `code`, `success` and `message`, along with whatever other fields are relevant for that response. However, we have a type and accidentally made the `message` field on `UpdatePostMutationResponse` nullable. While this may be harmless, if we do happen to omit the message in our resolver, it may go unnoticed until way later (hopefully during QA, but maybe in production!).

If we have these types implement a `MutationResponse` interface, though, we can ensure that our schema won't even build if there's any inconsistencies like that.

In this way, even if we never utilize `MutationResponse` as a return type for a field, we can still benefit from utilizing an Interface.

Comment: I can buy into using an interface as you say - as a "safety net" to ensure all response types aren't missing properties. Thanks for the response

Comment: What about for fragments? If an interface is used, then a fragment can be implemented on the interface based on my understanding?

Comment: Yes, but that would only work if your mutation field had the interface as a return type, as opposed to the concrete type (i.e. `MutationResponse` instead of just `UpdateUserMutationResponse`). That's possible, but it would also mean you would have one big fragment shared across all your mutations. I don't know if you would necessary gain anything by doing that beyond avoiding repeating the shared fields.

Comment: I created a simple type 
`interface MutationResponse {
    status: Boolean!
    errors: [Error]
}`

All the mutations use the interface. When creating the mutations, I created a fragment `fragment mutationResponseFields on MutationResponse {...}` that the utilize. The fragment works of the `MutationResponse` as well as the type that implements the interface. If you create a single fragment that implements the MutationResponse for all mutations, that would be another benefit of using interfaces for a mutation response?

Comment: Sure. In my opinion, having a single fragment potentially reduces the readability of your front end code. On the other hand, you eliminate accidentally omitting a common field like `status` or `errors` from one of your mutations, so there is some benefit to that approach.

Comment: The point I was trying to make in my answer, though, was that even if you didn't use the interface as your return type, there's still a benefit to implementing an interface from a schema design perspective.

Comment: You’re absolutely right and I agree with you. Schema design is one of the main reason to use an interface and fragments is another lesser benefit for mutation response types. In my testing, the mutation didn’t have to return the interface for the fragments to work off the interface. I’ve not used interfaces before, which is why I asked the question and I guess I was looking for confirmation that in addition to schema design, fragments is another benefit and I wasn’t misunderstanding something. Thanks